# PHP does not see the field in the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query:

```
insert into t_calls(`uniqueid`, `clid`, `first_answer_calls`, `duration`, 
`billsec`, `waitforanswer`, `disposition`, `typecalls`, `calldate`, 
`stprefix`, `stsuffix`, `filename`, `amaflags`) values('1395901608.476880', 
'+380688XXXXXX', '0', 0, 0, 0, 'CHANUNAVAIL', 1, '2014-03-27 06:26:48','157*', '', 
'IN_20140327-062648_+380688XXXXXX_-1_0_0','0001')
```

**My t_calls Table**

```
mysql> explain t_calls;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| uniqueid           | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| clid               | varchar(80)  | NO   | MUL |                     |       |
| first_answer_calls | varchar(32)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
| duration           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| billsec            | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| waitforanswer      | smallint(3)  | NO   | MUL | 0                   |       |
| disposition        | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| amaflags           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| typecalls          | tinyint(2)   | NO   | MUL | 0                   |       |
| calldate           | datetime     | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| stprefix           | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL |                     |       |
| stsuffix           | varchar(32)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                |       |
| filename           | varchar(254) | YES  |     |                     |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I execute this query via mysql CLI everything OK, but when I try it via PHP Mysqli I receive an error:

> 1054: Unknown column 'stsuffix' in 'field list')

What am I doing wrong?

MySQL Server version: 5.1.63-0+squeeze1-log
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch

```
$link= new mysqli($mysql_db, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass,"estprod");
$res=$link->query($query);
$errnum = $link->errno;
$errmsg = $link->error;
if ($errnum==0)
{
        echo "Query in file $data inserted.\n";
}
else
{
    if (($errnum==1037) or ($errnum==1038) or ($errnum==1040) or ($errnum==1041) or ($errnum==1105))
    {
        echo ("Error in MySQL server($errnum: $errmsg).");
    }elseif (($errnum==1044) or ($errnum==1045) or ($errnum==1053) or ($errnum==1142) or ($errnum==1143))
    {
        echo ("No GRANT for insert operation($errnum: $errmsg). HELP.");
    }elseif (($errnum==1054) or ($errnum==1058) or ($errnum==1064) or ($errnum==1065))
    {
        echo "Error execute mysql query($errnum: $errmsg). \n";
    }elseif (($errnum==1062))
    {
        echo "Query duplicate.\n";
    }else
    {
        echo "Unknow error: ($errnum) $errmsg\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code? how do you send the query? how do you build it? how do you connect to the database server / select the database?

Comment: What's with all the backlashes? Are you sure you are connecting to the right database?

Comment: There are a few letters in stsuffix that could be written in different languages - make sure its all the same in all your code and db.

Comment: 1) I connect to right database.
2) There is no typos, i checked twice

Comment: 3) there is *no* magic, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and check whether the column stsuffix is listed or not

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

- it is possible sometimes, you have created the field 'stsuffix' in
  the database table with some space like 'stsuffix '

  - So you better alter that field in that table and check if space
    exists.
  - if exist then remove it

Comment: When I execute this query via mysql CLI everything OK, but when I try it via PHP Mysqli I receive an error

Comment: did you try by using `stsuffix` like this in your query?

Comment: did you try using the back-stick around the `stsuffix` field in your query ?

Comment: there IS backticks around every field

Comment: this is a simple code to check the columns. so you can change it according to your db library

Comment: Yeap, the column exists  
[11] => Array
            (
                [Field] => stsuffix
                [Type] => varchar(32)
                [Null] => YES
                [Key] => MUL
                [Default] =>
                [Extra] =>
            )